# Trying to run expo local server and its telling me that I dont have development build installed?

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I am lost, because I don't know why I am being asked to create a local development build to run my expo app in ios simulator, because I never needed build to run it.

I simply ran command `npm start` and then pressed `i` to open my ios simulator without ever facing issues, but for some reason now I am being asked to install development build on the device first.

Here is the error:

```
 Opening on iOS...
CommandError: No development build (com.checka.myappnative) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.
```

My question is why can't i simply run my ios simulator like I always could, what changed?

Answer (score 8):

If you initiate a build either for Android nor for iOS, be carefull.
You'll have to switch to Expo Go by press "s" [on the terminal like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQpIE.png)

When that's done you can now press `i` or `a` to launch Expo Go on the simulator or on your device>

I hope that helps

Comment: Curious, whats the name of your vscode theme

Comment: @HamzaBashir my theme is: Tokyo Night

Comment: @EkimKael thanks, don't know that i have to switch to "Expo Go" first

Comment: Can it be something related to app flavors @EkimKael?

Comment: No I don't think so